# GLTF on demand and LOD for masive GLTF load

Tags: aframe, gltf

I am trying to load a very complex set of GLTF models in AFRAME.
My problem is very simple; my goal is to try to load about 9 million of gltf models in a unique scene.

My idea was to combine different level of detail in GLTF models depending on the camera distance and also only load those gltfs which are visible by the camera. If not the problem is that the assets are loaded in memory and my browser gets finally hung due to memory consumption.

Is this possible in AFRAME?

Answer (score 2):

With some attention to [A-Frame best practices](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/introduction/best-practices.md#performance), you should be able to make a performant scene with tens of thousands or even hundreds of thousands of polygons. But it will not be possible to load millions of distinct glTF models simultaneously in A-Frame, or any WebGL renderer for that matter.

Assuming you just want to show as many as models possible, try to take advantage of certain special cases:

1. If you need to render many copies of the same model, you can use a technique called "instancing". Check out [aframe-instancing](https://github.com/takahirox/aframe-instancing) for some example code on how to do that. Depending on the complexity of your model, you may be able to show thousands (but probably not millions) of copies at once.
2. If you're making something like an RPG — which needs many things in the world, but only a few are in sight at any given time — then you can be clever about dividing your world into zones, and only loading models for the current zone.

Both of these are non-trivial to implement, and beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question. My suggestion would be to try to get started on your own, and when you run into trouble, post new questions with the minimum amount of code necessary to see what you're trying to do. You may also find the [A-Frame Slack group](https://aframe.io/community/#slack) to be useful.